# Creating Config File for Custom Library in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I've looked through all of the CI documentation, and done some Googling of it, but I still can't quite seem to figure out how to create a configuration file for a custom library in codeigniter. If somebody could even just point me in the direction of where in the docs I could find my answer it would be greatly appreciated.

I am creating a library in CI that makes use of several database columns that can vary in name between applications, so I would like the names to be stored in a custom config file. Then I would like to be able to load these values in the construct of the library.

So my two questions are:

1.) How do I name the config file, and how do I name variables within that file so they don't overwrite any other config vars?

2.) How do I get the values from within my library?

Comment: you might want to point out what needs to be CI specific about it since a config file can be as easy as `return array('key' => 'val')` and be read in with `include`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When i have questions like this i like to look at other projects that already do this.  We utilized [`Tank_auth`](https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth) in almost all of our ci projects.  This is a popular authentication library, which has its own custome config files

1. It just creates its own config file in `application/config` directory.
   You could prefix your config items with your app name to ensure that they are unique
2. it then just [loads](https://github.com/ilkon/Tank-Auth/blob/master/application/libraries/Tank_auth.php#L27) it in the constructor:

   ```
   $this->ci->load->config('tank_auth', TRUE);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a `config/libraryname.php` file, it will be automatically loaded, just before library instanciation.

(so, beware of name conflicts with CI's config files)

Side note: this autoloading is disabled if you pass an array as the 2nd argument:

```
$this->load->library('thelibrary', array('param1' => 'value1'));
```

Answer (score 0):

in your config /config/your_conf.php:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config = Array(
        'your_conf1' => 'your_conf_val1',
        'your_conf2' => 'your_conf_val2',
        'your_conf3' => 'your_conf_val3'
    );
```

in your controller:

```
$this->config->load('your_conf');
var_dump((array)$this->config); //show all the configs including those in the your_conf.php
```